# PhoneGap: iOS/Android | save eMail attachment into PhoneGap-App

Tags: android, ios, email, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have same question about savin external files into my PhoneGap-App, but only from external App for example from eMail (attachment Files).
How can i do it? Is it plugin or this is only settings for my App?

[image: 'save into' eMail]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is URL scheme.

Here there are some information:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW21